# How to turn a single array into a multidimensional array using the values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array:

```php
$my_arr = ['folder1/', 'file2.png', 'file3.png', 'file4.png', 'file5.png', 'folder2/', 'file1.png', 'file6.png'];
```

And I want to make a multidimensional array categorized by the folders. Since it's not an associative array, I'm having trouble finding a way to split it on the folder values and having the files input into the same array.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to PHP and not finding anything on it thus far.

Comment: Does the folder must start with the string "folder"? What is the logic to know where to split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, one option for your example data could be to use a `foreach` and check if the string ends on a `/`

If is does, add it as a folder with an empty array and mark the current directory.
If it is not, add it to the current directory by using the foldername as the key.

```
$my_arr = ['folder1/', 'file2.png', 'file3.png', 'file4.png', 'file5.png', 'folder2/', 'file1.png', 'file6.png'];
$result = [];    
$folder = '';

foreach ($my_arr as $item) {
    if (substr($item, -1) === '/') {
        $folder = $item;
        $result[$folder] = [];
        continue;
    }
    $folder === '' ? $result[] = $item : $result[$folder][] = $item;
}

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [folder1/] => Array
        (
            [0] => file2.png
            [1] => file3.png
            [2] => file4.png
            [3] => file5.png
        )

    [folder2/] => Array
        (
            [0] => file1.png
            [1] => file6.png
        )

)
```

Comment: This is amazing. I was struggling for a few hours and you just saved my butt. Thanks!